# Importing .yml file to anaconda Error: "Solving environment: Failed. "

Tags: python, macos, conda

My friend saves all his dependencies in a .yml file.

```
name: CBGoogleScraper 
channels:
  - defaults 
dependencies:
  - alabaster=0.7.12=py37_0
  - appdirs=1.4.3=py37h28b3542_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py37_0
  - astroid=2.2.5=py37_0
  - atomicwrites=1.3.0=py37_1
  - attrs=19.1.0=py37_1
  - automat=0.7.0=py37_0
  - babel=2.6.0=py37_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.1.0=py37_0
  - ca-certificates=2019.1.23=0
  - certifi=2019.3.9=py37_0
  - cffi=1.12.2=py37h7a1dbc1_1
  - cloudpickle=0.8.1=py_0
  - colorama=0.4.1=py37_0
  - constantly=15.1.0=py37h28b3542_0
  - cryptography=2.6.1=py37h7a1dbc1_0
  - cssselect=1.0.3=py37_0
  - decorator=4.4.0=py37_1
  - defusedxml=0.5.0=py37_1
  - docutils=0.14=py37_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=py37_0

...
```

but when I try to import it in an environment I fail. The terminal gives the following message :

> Solving environment: failed.

I used the command

```bash
conda env update -f My-environment.yml
```

Comment: Could you add the `-v` flag to your command to see a more verbose output?